# how to store data, such as names of people, in adjacency list of a graph?

Tags: list, graph

I understand that we create an array of linked lists, representing each vertex by an index of the array. But how do we store the actual data associated with each vertex? For example, if I have a directed graph containing vertices as : 1. John 2. Mary 3. Sunny , and edges as (John,Mary) and (Mary,Sunny), we can create an adjacency list in the usual way with (1,2) and (2,3) as edges. But where do we store the names associated with 1,2 and 3?

**What did I do?**

I created a class 'vertexnode' which stores a name and a pointer to an object of class 'edgenode'.Then I created an array containing objects of class 'vertexnode'. The 'edgenode' class contains 1) an index of this array, where the index represents second endpoint of an edge, and 2) a pointer to the next object of 'edgenode'.  I then added vertices(names) and edges(pairs of names) to the graph. The program runs correctly.

I want to know whether this is a valid approach, or it is better to store names separately in an array, or there is some other method? Basically, I want to know how is it done conventionally?

**P.S.:** Please avoid using STL or Boost, or something similar in your answer.I am new to graphs, and I want to know how things work at the basic level, not some function which has already cooked the recipe for us. Thanks in advance.

Comment: anywhere around? it's better to give feedback when you have an answer...

Comment: Do you need both the numbers and the names of the nodes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have too much classes for this case, don't know if this is the best approach, but I would go with one class:

```
Vertex
{
   string name;
   List<Vertex> adjacent;
}
```

that way you can know which vertex is linked to which one, and you only have one class to store everything.

But I'd say that the best approach would be the one that fits your needs, and it depends on what you're gonna do with your graph

Comment: Thanks for the answer.I got it - "best approach would be the one that fits your needs". And sorry for my delay in providing feedback. I was not around.